# Android Crop during capturing image

Tags: android

i want to crop a image during capture not after capture.
like this image.
[image]

just replace save button with capture.
the rectangle should be realizable.just like the crop activity.
the thing i was doing was.
1st=capture image.
2nd=crop.

now i want to crop image during capture.
any help???

Comment: AFAIK The image capturing and cropping both are different activities so you can interact with single activity at a time.

Comment: You want to capture a image with cam and then crop the image right?

Comment: no i want to crop during capturing the image.

Comment: When do you want to crop? After clicking the "capture" button or when the view is shown?

Comment: after clicking the capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, Just think a different approach. Make a trick with [camera preview](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#camera-preview). Taking a picture usually requires that your users see a preview of their subject before clicking the shutter. To do so, you can use a SurfaceView to draw previews of what the camera sensor is picking up. Now create a [viewFinder](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/ViewfinderView.java#40) for your camera capture activity. Now your make the compatible code to change the viewFinder size dynamically, which allow you to select the region. And finally save the Image from bitmap view inside ViewFinder. This is exactly what you want. 
Please ask if you have not got my point. Best of luck.

Comment: i got your point you mean two layers.
1st layer of camera.
2nd layer to get the specific part of image.
but i need some code sample to understand how to integrate these layers.
because this is the first time i come to know about viewFinder.

Comment: Have you take a look on  **Google googles** (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil). Try to find goggles source code that will help you.